# Returning HTTP Status Code from Lambda via API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda setup with a Python handler, which I have created an API endpoint to receive only POST methods.  What I can't figure out is how my Lambda should tell the API Gateway that things have successfully completed and return a HTTP 200 status code.  Has anyone ventured down this path?

Answer (score 1):

In python lambda just do

```
raise Exception('notfound')
```

Instead of notfound use any other keyword.

Then in apigateway you need to map `'notfound'` to some response status code. I use swagger for this so here is example how to track `'notfound'`:

```
       "/tags/getById": {
          "get": {
            "summary": "Find the tag by it's ID",
            "produces": [
              "application/json"
            ],
            "responses": {
              "200": {
                "description": "successful operation",
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/Tag"
                }
              },
              "404": {
                "description": "No tag found"
              }
            },
            "parameters": [xxxxxxx],
            "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
              "requestTemplates": {xxxxx},
              "uri": {xxxxxx},
              "responses": {
                "default": {
                  "statusCode": "200"
                },
                "notfound": {
                  "statusCode": "404"
                }

              },
              "httpMethod": "POST",
              "type": "aws"
            }
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish your goal by using the returning value of your handler. See official [AWS Lambda Python Model Handler Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html).

You also need `API Gateway` properly configured with your `Integration Response`. You can find more information about how that's done in the official [API Gateway Introductory Blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-api-gateway-build-and-run-scalable-application-backends/), most important is the `Integration Response` section.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted other http error codes like 400 & 500 too, so I wrote an answer here. See it for further details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41343990/984471