# Return JSON with Lambda through API Gateway with mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to figure out how to map a Response from Lambda in the API Gateway to different status codes and at the same time receive a JSON object from my Lambda-function.

I have the following in Lambda:

```
context.done('Not Found:',jsonObject);
```

And in my API Gateway, in **integration response** I have a Lambda error regex on 403 saying **Not Found:.***.
This works, the method is returning a returning a 403.

The problem is I can't seem to return the **jsonObject**.
I have tried to create a application/json mapping template that looks like this (also under integration response):

```
{"error" : $input.json('$')}
```

But that only results in my response looking like this:

```
{"error" : {"errorMessage":"Not Found:"}}
```

Am I misunderstanding the mapping template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to stick with Lambda's default binding behavior, this approach looks promising.

[Is there a way to change the http status codes returned by Amazon API Gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329495/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-http-status-codes-amazon-api-gateway-returns)

Also Lambda will ignore the second parameter if the first `error` parameter is non-null.

Here's some cases how Lambda works.

### Case 1: The first parameter is null.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  context.done(null, {hello: 'world'});
}
```

Result: Lambda only returns the second parameter in JSON object.

```
{"hello": "world"}
```

### Case 2: The first parameter is non-null object.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  context.done({ping: 'pong'}, {hello: 'world'});
}
```

Result: Lambda automatically binds the first parameter to `errorMessage` value. Notice the second parameter `{hello: 'world'}` is dropped off.Better not to pass object as it results in `[object Object]`.

```
{"errorMessage": "[object Object]"}
```

### Case 3: The first parameter is non-null string.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  context.done('pingpong', {hello: 'world'});
}
```

Result: Lambda automatically binds the first parameter to `errorMessage` value. Notice the second parameter `{hello: 'world'}` is dropped off.

```
{"errorMessage": "pingpong"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your template to this:

```
{"error" : $input.json('$').errorMessage}
```

$input.json('$') is supposed to represent the JSON object returned by lambda.