# Lambda return only 200 respose code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a sample lambda function for producing success & error responses. function is like below

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
if(event.val1=="1")
{
 callback(null, 'success');
}else
{
 callback(true, 'fail');
}
};
```

When i have tested this function using API Gateway , I got different response body, But the response code is Same (always return 200 ok response code).

Is it possible to customize status code from lambda function(eg: need 500 for error responses & 200 for success responses)?

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/a/31371862/1428388 useful?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at API Gateway's new simplified [Lambda proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html) feature.

Using this you can define your status codes, return headers and body content directly from your Lambda.

Example from docs:

```
'use strict';
console.log('Loading hello world function');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var name = "World";
    var responseCode = 200;
    console.log("request: " + JSON.stringify(event));
    if (event.queryStringParameters !== null && event.queryStringParameters !== undefined) {
        if (event.queryStringParameters.name !== undefined && event.queryStringParameters.name !== null && event.queryStringParameters.name !== "") {
            console.log("Received name: " + event.queryStringParameters.name);
            name = event.queryStringParameters.name;
        }

        if (event.queryStringParameters.httpStatus !== undefined && event.queryStringParameters.httpStatus !== null && event.queryStringParameters.httpStatus !== "") {
            console.log("Received http status: " + event.queryStringParameters.httpStatus);
            responseCode = event.queryStringParameters.httpStatus;
        }
    }

    var responseBody = {
        message: "Hello " + name + "!",
        input: event
    };
    var response = {
        statusCode: responseCode,
        headers: {
            "x-custom-header" : "my custom header value"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(responseBody)
    };
    console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(response))
    context.succeed(response);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to send a custom error code from AWS API GW you should use response mapping template in integration response.
You basically define a regular expression for each status code you'd like to return from API GW.

Steps:

- Define Method Response for each status code [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/method-response/)
- Define Integration Response RegEx for each status mapping to the Correct Method Response [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration-response/)

Using this configuration the HTTP return code returned by API GW to the client is the one matching the regular expression in **"selectionPattern"**.

Finally I strongly suggest to use an API GW framework to handle these configuration, [Serverless](https://serverless.com/) is a very good framework.

Using Servereless you can define a template as follows (*serverless 0.5 snippet*):

```
myResponseTemplate:
application/json;charset=UTF-8: |
#set ($errorMessageObj = $util.parseJson($input.path('$.errorMessage'))) {
    "status" : $errorMessageObj.status,
    "error":{
        "error_message":"$errorMessageObj.error.message",
        "details":"$errorMessageObj.error.custom_message"
    }
}
responsesValues:
'202':
  selectionPattern: '.*"status": 202.*'
  statusCode: '202'
  responseParameters: {}
  responseModels: {}
  responseTemplates: '$${myResponseTemplate}'
'400':
  selectionPattern: '.*"status": 400.*'
  statusCode: '400'
  responseParameters: {}
  responseModels: {}
  responseTemplates: '$${myResponseTemplate}'
```

Then simply return a json object from your lambda, as in the following python snippet (*you can use similar approach in nodejs*):

```
 def handler(event, context):
     # Your function code ...
     response = { 
         'status':400, 
         'error':{
             'error_message' : 'your message',
             'details' : 'your details'
          }
     }
    return response
```

I hope this helps.

G.