# AWS API Gateway: Is it possible to return 302 when using custom authorizer?

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, http-redirect

I have an AWS API setup that works correctly. I use a custom authorizer and I can return 401 if the user doesn't have the correct token. Is it possible however to redirect the user to our Authorization service where they would authenticate and get the authorization token?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329495/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-http-status-codes-returned-by-amazon-api-gateway) answer I can setup the http codes for an API gateway, but when using a custom authorizer the authorizer expects a policy as response from Lambda. What should I do in that case?

Comment: API Gateway doesn't allow to change the response for unauthorized case, but you are welcome to stack the API to the other API and re-map the status code and the location header.

Comment: May be use cognito as your authorizer to integrate your third party service authorization?