# Error handling patterns in Amazon API Gateway and AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a simple lambda function having following code.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const operation = event.body.operation;
    console.log("operation = ", operation)
    switch (operation) {
        case 'add': callback(null, 'post method');
            break;
        case 'add1': callback(null, {
            status: 0,
            errorType: "InternalServerError",
            errorCode: "001",
            errorMessage: "post method error."
        }
        );
        default: callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
            break;
    }
};
```

It will be connected with Amazon API Gateway. Using a REST client able to get success & error responses. But HTTP status code is still 200. Then I have modified API Gateway integration responses in two ways.

```
 1. Selection pattern : “InternalServerError”
 2. Selection pattern : “.*InternalServerError”
    Method response : 500
```

But I still got 200 HTTP status code. What is the actual issue related with this selection patterns?

Comment: Do you perhaps need to use [`context.fail()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31329495/1695906)?  (Scroll down past the accepted answer and read the others.)

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway checks for the error pattern when the error is thrown from Lambda function using context.fail(). Refer to this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/error-handling-patterns-in-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/) for more details on handling Lambda error in API GW.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to return a proper HTTP response, from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708017/aws-lambda-api-gateway-error-malformed-lambda-proxy-response/43718963#43718963):