# How can I get a Lambda using AWS Gateway to return HTTP error status code in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to return status error codes (ex. 500, 400, 401) through my AWS Gateway and can't seem to figure it out.

I've seen a few examples, where they do something like:

```
return context.fail('Bad Request: You submitted invalid input');
```

However, there is no fail or succeed methods on the `ILambdaContext` object.

Here's what I've got so far (non-working)

Lambda Code:

```
 var addressresponse = new AddressValidationResponse();
            addressresponse.Errors = new string[1];
            addressresponse.Errors[0] = "test error";
            addressresponse.Reason = "client_error";

 return addressresponse;
```

[image: Custom Error model]

[image: Integration Response]

[image: Method Response]

I think I'm close, but I'm still getting a 200 back with the response of:

```
{
  "Reason": "client_error",
  "Errors": [
    "test error"
  ]
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need throw an exception in your C# lambda function and use the API gateway console to map a specific error code to the HTTP response code in the response mapping templates.

Comment: I thought I tried that following http://marcelog.github.io/articles/aws_api_gateway_return_custom_http_status_codes.html .  No luck though, I posted a bunch of screen shots in the hopes that somebody might see something I'm not seeing.

Comment: Yep, this + throwing an exception in c# lets me set the status code.  Add the exception part, let me know and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse to wrap your response, like below:

```
public static async Task<APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse?> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
{
    var response = new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse();
    try
    {
        response.Body = await DoSomeWorkAsync();
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        response.Body = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { error = ex.Message }) ;
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I answered something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708017/aws-lambda-api-gateway-error-malformed-lambda-proxy-response/43718963#43718963)

Basically you need to return a response object that APIG recognises.

There's C# example [here](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/amazon-web-services-2/serverless-in-csharp/)

I would say I don't C# in the context Lambda though, basically you need to return headers, statusCode and response Body.

Comment: That makes sense, I copy pasted the code (and added error text) from the c# example and commented mine out, however I still get a 200 from the lambda with the error body. I set up a regex to check for error.*, but no luck.  Do I need to specify any mapping templates or custom headers to get the Response object (from the link) to work with the gateway?

Comment: This is incorrect, in c# an exception needs to be thrown that ties into an integration response regex.

Comment: Aha there you go!