# I couldn't find error in AWS Lambda + DynamoDB Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am currently studying AWS Lambda, Dynamodb, and API Gateway.
I was developing a serverless API that simply creates a user and retrieves a user matching the ID. I tried a lot and searched, but I asked a question because of the 'Internal Server Error' that could not be resolved.

When I first discovered this error, I saw that it was because the return format was incorrect, so I used a return value that included isBase643Encoded, statusCode, headers, multiValueHeaders, and body, and used a string as well as body. However, when the error was not resolved and only statusCode and body existed among many attempts, INFO Success was confirmed to occur in CloudWatch Logs.

```
INFO    Success {
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: 'requestId...',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  }
}
```

Below is the code of the lambda function that receives and processes the body value of name and password through POST method.

```js
import { DynamoDBClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb'
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient, PutCommand } from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb'
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda'
import { v4 } from 'uuid'

const dynamo = new DynamoDBClient({})
const client = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(dynamo)

export const handler = async (events: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  const body = JSON.parse(events.body!)

  const command = new PutCommand({
    TableName: "DynamoUsers",
    Item: {
      id: v4(),
      name: body.name,
      password: body.password
    },
  })

  await client.send(command)

  try {
    // await client.send(command)
    // console.log('name', body.name)
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: "Hello World"
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // console.log('err', err)
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: "Hello World"
    }
  }
}
```

I confirmed that returning the Hello, World string through the GET method without any db connection worked without any problem.

```js
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda'

export const handler = async (_: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: "Hello World"
  }
}
```

API Gateway, Lambda functions, Lambda layers, etc. were written in Terraform. The code below is terraform code that handles the user-generated lambda function part.

```
# [POST] /users
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "users_create" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api_gateway.id

  integration_uri = aws_lambda_function.users_create.invoke_arn
  integration_type = "AWS_PROXY"
  integration_method = "POST"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "users_create" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api_gateway.id

  route_key = "POST /users"
  target = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.users_create.id}"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "api_gw_users_create" {
  statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.users_create.function_name
  principal = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api_gateway.execution_arn}/*/*"
}
```

I'm sorry that I don't have much knowledge as I just started learning.

Comment: Hi, so what's the issue? It says success.

Comment: Creating users in dynamodb works without problems. However, in the result of the request sent to Postman, {
     "message": "Internal Server Error"
} The value is returned.

Comment: And what can you see in the CloudWatch group for the Lambda? What's the full output for an invocation that triggers the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read over the following troubleshooting article which should help you fix your issue:

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway

more here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-troubleshooting-lambda.html

and here:

[AWS lambda api gateway error "Malformed Lambda proxy response"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708017/aws-lambda-api-gateway-error-malformed-lambda-proxy-response)