# Throw a particular status code based on the JSON request input - API Gateway endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, endpoint

I am creating a Mock endpoint to work on a development project.

I want to throw certain response codes based on the strings in the JSON request body.

E.g.

```
{ "desiredResponse": "200" }
```

Would return a response code of 200.

```
{ "desiredResponse": "400" }
```

Would return a response code of 400.

From my understanding, this is not possible via the Mock Integration Response 
(Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html)

Is this possible via a Lambda function?  Or is there any possible workarounds for this?

Due to the nature of this project, I do not want to use request Query Strings or Header to set the response code.

I have seen the workarounds here, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html but I really need the response code to be dependant on the request data.

Comment: This would be easily done with a [Lambda Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Use a [Lambda Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html)
to output a particular error to the JSON response body.

Then, use the [API Integration Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329495/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-http-status-codes-returned-by-amazon-api-gateway) to map the error string to the particular status code using the Lambda Error Regex field.