# How can I change the status code of App sync AWS?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api, aws-appsync

That's the error data returned from App Sync AWS:
{
    "data": {
        "getContentById": null
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "path": [
                "getContentById"
            ],
            "data": null,
            "errorType": "Lambda:Handled",
            "errorInfo": null,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 2,
                    "sourceName": null
                }
            ],
            "message": "ID is not found"
        }
    ]
}
How can I change the 200 Status code from my lambda function?
[Screen shot from PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiWGZ.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329495/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-http-status-codes-returned-by-amazon-api-gateway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you cannot customize the error status code in AWS AppSync. The suggested approach is to use `errorType` in the error response. You can use `$util.appendError` or `$util.error` methods in your velocity mapping template to define the error type.

Comment: do you know if there are plans to implement this feature? Do you know if there is a roadmap to see how likely is some feature to be implemented, or even to propose one?

Comment: Is this answer still the case? I'm not a fan

Comment: @greenie-beans i am considering dropping aws appsync because of these silly design decisions

Comment: i'm pretty sure that graphql sends 200 responses for everything by default. we ended up creating some custom errors based on the parent answer, and then the client parsed out any errors based on the `errors` key. this blog post has some background on graphql and errors: https://sachee.medium.com/200-ok-error-handling-in-graphql-7ec869aec9bc