# API Response Mapping Lambda Error in GO is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am unable to map error from lambda to Status Code 400.

My lambda code in Go is as follows

```
package main

import (
    "errors"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func main() {

    lambda.Start(returnError)
}

func returnError() error {

    return errors.New("Something went wrong!")
}
```

I have added Response Integration to Status Code 400 as follows.

[image]

Still I get response Status Code 200 as follows. I want it to be 400

[image]

I am already using mapping template for request and response. I want to separate Lambda from mapping & validation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup Lambda as Proxy integration and then write to return status code from lambda as 400.

Here is an existing post:
[Is there a way to change the http status codes returned by Amazon API Gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329495/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-http-status-codes-returned-by-amazon-api-gateway)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned in the Question. I don't want to use proxy. I am already mapping template for request and response. I want to separate Lambda from mapping & validation.