# Return the expected status code in Postman

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I am using Lambda function to return custom responses for my api endpoint.

i am returning the responses like this -

```
response404 = {
        "statusCode": 404,
        "body": json.dumps({"message": "Not Found"})
        }
        
        if httpStatusCode == "200":
            return output_response
        else:
            return response404
```

It's returning the response but not setting the status code in Postman.

[image: 404]

What do i need to do to set the status to 404 in postman as well.

Comment: What web framework does your api use?  Flask?  Django REST?  Something else?

Comment: It's a REST api in aws api gateway

Comment: By framework he meant the language framework Python Framework is Flask, JS has express. Also are you lambda proxy integration?This should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/39936210/13126651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by setting up a Lambda Proxy Integration.

[image]

The response of the lambda function needs to be in this format ->

```
response = {
        "statusCode": 404,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        },
        "body": json.dumps(error_handler)
    }

return response
```