# AWS API Gateway integration response regex not matching with Lambda error

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I wrote something in Lambda that raises an error, and the api gateway should see the error and response with status code 401. However it doesn't matter what I put in the regex field it will always response with 200. (And yes, the Lambda function I wrote in Golang actually raises an error, instead of returning a JSON string)

This is the response I was trying to match:

```
{"errorMessage":"401","errorType":"errorString"}
```

I've tried putting these regex in the HTTP status regex.

```
.*\"401\".*
.*401.*
401
.*
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qDB8.png)

And all of them return status code 200

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329495/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-http-status-codes-returned-by-amazon-api-gateway