Custom HTTP response codes in AWS Lambda custom runtime with function URLs
I built an AWS Lambda custom runtime function to be triggered through function URLs for a streaming response. I don't see how I can set the HTTP response code, such as 404 or 500. I know it's possible for most HTTP codes in the supported runtimes, like NodeJS. Is it possible with custom runtimes?

I know this is not your case exactly, but perhaps still helpful since a lot of different applications and methods are discussed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329495/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-http-status-codes-returned-by-amazon-api-gateway.
